# Android Seekbar float with values

Tags: android, android-seekbar

Hi i am new for android and in my app i have one seeckBar for measuring persons height's ,
My seeckBar min range is--->2 and max range is---->8

Here i want to show my seeckBar values like 2.0,2.1,2.5.....2.12,

After 2.12 i want to show seeckBar range is 3ft's in that way process is need going up to 8ft's

How can i do this can some one help me please

### code:-

```
SeekBar height_seeckBar = (SeekBar) view.findViewById(R.id.height_seeckBar);
            final int min = 2;
            height_seeckBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                    float value = min + (float) ((float) progress / 10.0);
                    total_height.setText("" + value + "(ft)");
                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

How many values there are between two integers? -> `13`

How many integers are needed? `8 - 2 = 6`

How many values in overall? -> `13 * 6 = 78` (max value of `Seekbar`)

How to show the value?

`(progress / 13) + "." + (progress % 13) + "(ft)"`

Answer (score 1):

So the least count should be 1 inch. Set the max value of the `SeekBar` in terms of inches. So from 2ft to 8ft, the range should be 6ft. Which is **72 inches**. Set your `SeekBar`'s maximum to 72.

```
android:max="72"
```

Then in code, manipulate it as:

```
int inches = 24+mSeekBar.getProgress(); //24 is added since we start from 2ft(12")
String ht=String.valueOf(inches/12) +"."+String.valueOf(inches%12); //This can be displayed on a TextView for the user.
```

Answer (score 0):

They way I solved this is not using 1, but 2 scroll bars. So that if someone needed to use floats, they can use the 2nd one. Just make sure the user get propper feedback on what they do...

From memory you can concat them together. Works better with being on the imperial system with the " and ' then on the metric.